# Netbeans 7.3 showing warning CSS class not found even when it is present and working in JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp, netbeans-7.3

I recently upgraded to netbeans 7.3, and now I am facing a problem. When I went through my previous code, for some css classes in jsp file it is showing that css class class not found and add reference.

Even when I am writing new code, again for some classes it is not showing warning but for some it does. Below I am attaching an image in which I attach a global.css file and in jsp for `id="content-container"` it is going fine but for `class="table-form"` it is showing warning that this class not found and in hint, it is showing option to add reference to css file. And on clicking on this link nothing happens.

Any Idea?

[image: I am including css file still showing warning]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when i created a copy of an html file.

As the answer above suggested, i just changed the path to the external CSS file (added one character), saved once, changed it back to the original/correct one and the CSS class warnings disappeared.

Worked for me on Netbeans 7.4 Patch 3 (Build 201310111528)

Comment: Wow, NetBeans. That is silly... had the same issue with 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a fix for this, but have found a work around you could try. 
Including the context path in the href seems to fix this:

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
```

This only works for me sometimes... but editing the href value and saving seems to get Netbeans to re-parse the page.

Answer (score 0):

With NetBeans 8.0.2 i had to close the project and create it again using option "New Project with existing sources".